# Anyway to shorten these for statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just seeing if there is anyway to shorten these for statements?

```
...      
      fillMonthSelect: function() {
        var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

        for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
          $('.card-expiry-month').append($('<option value="'+i+'" '+(month === i ? "selected" : "")+'>'+i+'</option>'));
        }
      },

      fillYearSelect: function() {
        var year = new Date().getFullYear();

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
          $('.card-expiry-year').append($("<option value='"+(i + year)+"' "+(i === 0 ? "selected" : "")+">"+(i + year)+"</option>"));
        }
      },
...
```

Answer (score 3):

String building in code is typically messy, especially without a native `String.Format()` or `sprintf()`  in Javascript. Building HTML is the worst offender, too.

Other than using a templating engine, like [ICanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/) (which this use case alone doesn't really justify), you could also build a helper function for creating option tags.

```
function buildOption(value, isSelected) {
    return "<option value='"+value+"' "+(isSelected ? "selected" : "")+">"+value+"</option>";
}
```

If you're building a lot of these drop-down options, it might makes things more readable:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var option = buildOption(i + year, i === 0);
    $('.card-expiry-year').append(option);
}
```

It's a good idea to avoid long lines/sections of code which have a simple purpose, but have to be read carefully to understand what they do (complicated regular expressions are a good example).

Extracting that functionality into a function avoids this, because the function signature is all someone would need to read to understand what it does.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things I'd do to pretty up the code.  First, you are looking up the same element with every loop iteration.  I know it's common, but it is very inefficient and leads towards long lines.

I moved a couple of things into variables, with also split up those long lines and made the code far more readable, IMHO.

Try something like this instead:

```
  fillMonthSelect: function() {
    var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var el = $('.card-expiry-month');
    var selectedFlag;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      selectedFlag = (month === i ? "selected" : "");
      el.append($('<option value="'+i+'" '+ selectedFlag +'>'+i+'</option>'));
    }
  },
```

The next step would be to get a formatString function, so you could simply write something like:

```
  formatString("<option value='{0}' {1}>{0}</option>", i, selectedFlag);
```